# How can I redirect by clicking button two different page based on age?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

If 30-41 years >Button > go to a website.......

Otherwish 42-99 years  > same button >go to another website.

Here is my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqCo2CuvPP5Sm_olIZFoovXBlsiG0H6o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I doubt this is not possible without actually asking a visitor their age ..?

Comment: Please include any code in the question itself, not in an inaccessible third-party site.   See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your html with changed code. Enjoy! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Add your Age</title>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="datepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="dobday"></select>
        <select id="dobmonth"></select>
        <select id="dobyear"></select>
        <button id="buttonOK" style="margin-left: 40px;background:orange;padding: 10px 25px; " >Ok</button>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.dobPicker({
                    daySelector: '#dobday', /* Required */
                    monthSelector: '#dobmonth', /* Required */
                    yearSelector: '#dobyear', /* Required */
                    dayDefault: 'Day', /* Optional */
                    monthDefault: 'Month', /* Optional */
                    yearDefault: 'Year', /* Optional */
                    minimumAge: 18, /* Optional */
                    maximumAge: 99 /* Optional */
                });
            });
            
            $( "#buttonOK" ).click(function() {
                const yearDiff = new Date().getFullYear() - $("#dobyear").find(":selected").text();
                if( yearDiff > 30 && yearDiff < 41){
                    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                }
                else if(yearDiff >= 41 && yearDiff < 99){
                    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
                }
                else{
                    window.location.href = "http://yahoo.com";
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its work out dear,Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is there to rescue.

HTML:

```html
<button onclick="navigation()">Click</button>
```

JavaScript

```js
<script>
function navigation(){
  var age = 40; // Not sure how you detect age
  if (age>=30 && age<=41)
      window.open("http://www.website1.com");
  else if (age>=42 && age<=99)
      window.open("http://www.website2.com");
}
</script>
```